Possible to access old Seagate Central NAS from iPad?
Does anyone know of a way to browse and open files in a private area on an old Seagate Central NAS using e.g. Files on an iPad?
The NAS is circa 2014; at the time it provided iOS apps, they appear to no longer exist.
The NAS supports SMB (v1 I think) but this appears to no longer work from any modern device.
The NAS also supports straight FTP (not SFTP) but I haven't found an iOS app that will then open the files.
It also supports DLNA, but this is for the 'public' areas of the NAS; we need a login-based access to files in a 'private' area.
My daughter had a MacBook that could access 'her' area on the NAS, but this has been returned to her school; so the only way I can get on to her area of the NAS to open files is with FTP from my Debian.
The network is a private, home-based LAN.

You no longer have administrative access to the NAS?

You could try to enable SMB1 on your Linux box (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265923/configuring-20-04-samba-for-smbv1), mount the NAS and expose the mount point via SMB (modern version) for the iPad to access.

@MarcWilson - yes, I have admin access

@nohillside - thanks, yes, I can see how that could work, hmm, I might give it a try ...

I don't know if this is a "feature" of your NAS or not, but in addition to setting the SMB version to 1, you may also need to set something called NTLM to ver 1 also.
